# What is the button in keyboard to stop JavaScript loop?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'd like to stop alert messagebox from keep showing after several times?

```
var arr =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

Is there any shortcut key in keyboard to jump out of the loop in Chrome?

Comment: There is [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break).

Comment: ouch.. my head hurts

Comment: unless the disable alerts checkobox is present, there isn't

Comment: try using ESC key to stop loading

Comment: Try writing the output to the console instead of an alert. It's much less painful that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To directly answer your question, Chrome-based browsers provide a checkbox on dialog windows to prevent them from showing up repeatedly. This checkbox appears the second time the same dialog shows up.

If you're debugging, consider using [`console.log`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-write) or [inserting breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) to your code. The latter will provide you with controls to step over, step through and step out of code as well as tools to inspect your code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what your asking. Especially regarding a keyboard?

**But**, you can count the alerts and then hide after a certain amount with something like below *(if that's what you are getting at).*

```
var i = 0;

function countAlerts() {
  i++;

  alert("I am alert box number" + ' ' + (i));

  if (i > 4) { // alert limit

    alert(""); // empty alert
    $(".alertselector").hide(); // hide container div

    self.close();    
  }    
}
```